# Black video in VLC, dragon player and mplayer after Maverick Meerkat update

Tags: linux, video, maverick

I use Kubuntu and recently upgraded from lucid lynx 10.04 to maverick meerkat release 10.10.

Today I noticed that video playback is broken.  Output from every video player I have tried is black, however I can hear the audio.

I've tried googling this problem and found some old links to similar problems people have found in the past and tried all remedies but none of them have worked.

Do others have this problem and have you managed to solve it?

**EDIT**

By the way, this is ANY video content.  I'm using the Nvidia nonfree driver

**EDIT2**
I've discovered that in Dragon player, if I open up the video settings and increase the contrast, the video shows.  But it's in black & white.  Then, if I slide the saturation bar, colour then appears.  If I click the defaults button it then puts the sliders back to their original positions but now the video is showing.

This is very weird.  I've also noticed that skype video doesn't show in the preferences pain - preview section.  But it does when I alter video settings in an open movie in dragon player.  But as soon as dragon player is closed skype video returns to it's normal black shade.

Comment: I have a similar issue but a refresh fixes it for me.  I can't isolate it any further for this reason.  sorry.

Comment: Which exact video card are we talking about here? What driver version are you on? Are there other versions available to choose from in Synaptic?

Comment: Nvidia. Driver version is. 173.14.28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it.  This is what I did.

In Kubuntu, open up the Nvidia XServer settings.

If necessary click to expand "X Screen 0".
Select "X Server XVidio Settings".

Unchecked "Sync to VBlank".

And quit.

Video now shows correctly.

Now, I turned back on the VBlank feature and video still shows correctly.
I'm suspecting something has been written into a configuration file somewhere that was missing.

Regardless, it's working now and I'm happy about that.  It's bothered me for over a month!